# How can the AWS timestream dimensions value be updated?

Tags: amazon-timestream

Currently, lets assume I have 2 dimensions (Car, Model) and the corresponding measure/value.
Now, I want to add a 3rd dimension (Location) in the records that I write in future. Since the 3rd dimension (Location) is empty for the earlier records that I have written, is there a way that I can update records with empty "Location" dimension to a default value.

This is required as I want to query now based on the "Location". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

AWS's Timestream uses the dimensions plus the time as "key" for updates and, in your case, having a new dimension means a new key is generated. You'll have data WITH the location and WITHOUT the location were car, model and time would be the same.

In theory, you could insert all the data WITH the location dimension then delete all the records that doesn't have a location set. But I believe it would require two operations.

Let us know how you decided to do, ok? I got curious!

Good luck!